# How to create a vector of repeated strings based on a different vector

Tags: r, string

I'm trying to have a vector of strings with repeated values like this:

```
[1] "subcarinal, subcarinal"
[2] "subcarinal, subcarinal, subcarinal"
```

I want the number of repetitions of each word to be based on a different vector:

```
x<-  2 0 2 3
```

I want the output to be in this case:

```
[1] "subcarinal, subcarinal"
[2] ""
[3] "subcarinal, subcarinal"
[4] "subcarinal, subcarinal, subcarinal"
```

I have tried this and it doesn't work:

```
dat <- data.frame(name=rep("subcarinal", times=c(x)))
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `rep`, `toString` and `map`:

```
library(purrr)

string<-'subcarinal'

map_chr(x, ~toString(rep(string, .x)))

[1] "subcarinal, subcarinal"            
[2] ""                                  
[3] "subcarinal, subcarinal"            
[4] "subcarinal, subcarinal, subcarinal"
```

Comment: Good idea using `toString`!

Comment: Thank you, this was great!

Answer (score 1):

We may use `strrep` from `base R`

```
dat <- data.frame(name = trimws(strrep("subcarinal, ", x), whitespace = ",\\s*"))
```

-output

```
> dat
                                name
1             subcarinal, subcarinal
2                                   
3             subcarinal, subcarinal
4 subcarinal, subcarinal, subcarinal
```

---

Or using `rep`

```
data.frame(name = mapply(function(u, v) toString(rep(u, v)), 
      rep("subcarinal", length(x)), x))
```

#### data

```
x <- c(2, 0, 2, 3)
```

Comment: My best try: `tibble(string, x) %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  uncount(x) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(string = paste(string, collapse = ", ")) %>%
  slice(1)`. Then I tried to use complete to add an empty second row but no success.